# How do I install two different versions of the same application on SteamOS 3.0, an Arch Linux based OS?

Tags: arch-linux, steam, emulation

Got a steamdeck recently and have been setting it up for emulation. It's running SteamOS 3.0 which, from what I could find, is based on Arch Linux. I need two versions of PPSSPP. The latest build for most of my library and v1.10.3 specifically to play Phantasy Star Portable 2 Infinity over the internet with friends. I'm able to downgrade the currently installed flatpak to this version but now I've hit a roadblock trying to install the latest build without overwriting the other. Having never used Linux before in my life...I'm lost.

Comment: Are you trying to install two different versions of the same `flatpak` or of a dependency?

Comment: Two different versions of the same flatpak. Right now I have v1.10.3 installed for P2Pi and I also want to install the current build v1.13.1 for the rest of my PSP library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no good way to install two different versions of the same Flatpak because Flatpak-applications get stored in the same path. Therefore, you cannot upgrade/downgrade without overwriting the currently installed application. I'm not familiar with the SteamDeck but I know that it is an immutable system, like, say Fedora Silverblue.

The *default* installation method for Flatpaks is system-wide, so I'm guessing that it's the same for SteamOS.
You could try installing the same package passing the `--user` flag in the command line, e.g.

```
flatpak list --columns=app,version,installation     # lists all the app versions and type of installation (system/user)

### if PPSSPP is installed on 'system' try the commands below ###

# user also requires adding the flathub repo to the user repos
flatpak remote-add --user --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

flatpak install --user flathub org.ppsspp.PPSSPP    # install for the current user
```

*Should* work, but Flatpaks weren't designed for this use-case. If the above doesn't work, you might have to resort to more "hacky" ways of resolving the issue.

Comment: I ran these commands but I don't know where to find the executable for v1.13.1. Discover is still telling me there is an update for PPSSPP available so it would seem I now have both versions but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: You can try to run `flatpak run --user org.ppsspp.PPSSPP` and `flatpak run org.ppsspp.PPSSPP`. SteamOS uses KDE, and KDE allows you to bind keyboard shortcuts to run specific commands; that way, you don't need to open the terminal each time you want to run specific versions.

Comment: So I managed to get it working. I had to set up an extra installation path as per instructions here: https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/tips-and-tricks.html It was finicky but I now have bit v1.10.3 and v1.13.1 installed. All that remains is setting up the SRM parsers.